# What kind of geometric-like summation is this, and does it have a solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Thank you, I was running investment numbers when the following summation came up:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^N(1+i_1)^n(1+i_2)^{N-n}
$$

Does this have a closed solution like the geometric series does? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Just curious... Is it a valuation at maturity of a bond? (If so I think it there is a slight error in the first factor $(1+i_1)^n$ - where I think about  $i_1$ as a coupon interest rate and $i_2$ some valuation interest rate)

Comment: @AD.: Hi AD, that's interesting to notice. I am using this in my retirement planning spreadsheet! The first term will be the inflation rate and the second is the bond/investment interest rate. I wanted to see what it would look like to even the payment burden--in this case, for my payment to be a constant proportion of inflation throughout the duration of investment, instead of a constant payment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **is** a finite geometric series. You are finding 
$$(1+i_2)^N\sum_{n=0}^N  \left(\frac{1+i_1}{1+i_2}\right)^n.$$

**Remark:** If $i_2=-1$, then one cannot do the division. However, the numbers $i_1$ and $i_2$ look like interest rates, so are presumably non-negative.

Comment: +1) But perhaps something should be added in the case $i_2=-1$.

Comment: Wow, I sure didn't recognize it. Thanks for your help! I will accept shortly.

Comment: @AD.: I expect that $i_1$ and $i_2$ are interest rates.

Comment: @AD.: Probably, though in this application $i_{1}$ and $i_{2}$ are interest rates and I have seen these equations typically state they are true for all but the -1 case.

Comment: Btw, did you know that the Danish and the Swiss market do have negative interest rates since about 8 months ago or so? (On the other hand I guess they are far from -100%... :)

Comment: Sounds useful, my car is close to defunct.